# Is it okay to reference WebClient from my MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, ioc-container

I need to download a page from my controller and use Webclient to do so, which isn't Mockable?  How do I test around this or can I just leave the direct reference in there?

Answer (score 3):

You could define a repository interface and in the implementation of this repository use WebClient. Then your controller will work with the repository and because it is an interface it is easily mockable. Now you will say that this is simply delegating the problem of unit testing the implementation of the repository which is now using WebClient and which is not mockable. The answer to this is that that's no longer an unit test and quite frankly testing a method like this:

```
public string FetchData(string url)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
```

doesn't make much sense as you are now testing the WebClient class which I hope has already been done by its authors in Redmond.